# Using Word2Vec for polysemy solving problems

Tags: nlp, word2vec

I have some questions about Word2Vec:

1. What determines the dimension of the result model vectors?
2. What is elements of this vectors?
3. Can I use Word2Vec for polysemy solving problems (state = administrative unit vs state = condition), if I already have texts for every meaning of words?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(1) You pick the desired dimensionality, as a meta-parameter of the model. Rigorous projects with enough time may try different sizes, to see what works best for their qualitative evaluations.

(2) Individual dimensions/elements of each word-vector (floating-point numbers),  in vanilla word2vec are not easily interpretable. It's only the arrangement of words as a whole that has usefulness – placing similar words near each other, and making relative directions (eg "towards 'queen' from 'king'") match human intuitions about categories/continuous-properties. And, because the algorithms use explicit randomization, and optimized multi-threaded operation introduces thread-scheduling randomness to the order-of-training-examples, even the exact same data can result in different (but equally good) vector-coordinates from run-to-run.

(3) Basic word2vec doesn't have an easy fix, but there's a bunch of hints of polysemy in the vectors, and research work to do more to disambiguate contrasting senses.

For example, generally more-polysemous word-tokens wind up with word-vectors that are some combination of their multiple senses, and (often) of a smaller-magnitude than less-polysemous words.

This [early paper](https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=2390645) used multiple representations per word to help discover polysemy. Similar later papers like [this one](https://arxiv.org/abs/1610.07569v1) use clustering-of-contexts to discover polysemous words then relabel them to give each sense its own vector.

[This paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1601.03764v2) manages an impressive job of detecting alternate senses via postprocessing of normal word2vec vectors.