# What are the state-of-art algorithms for resolving words polysemy/homonymy?

Tags: nlp, wordnet

I tried to solve the word-polysemy problem (fix WordNet-synsets for polysemy words in the text) via word2vec-like neural networks ([Using Word2Vec for polysemy solving problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51330549/using-word2vec-for-polysemy-solving-problems)), but it give too poor results.
What are other state-of-art algorithms for resolving words polysemy/homonymy? Can you give me some articles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start with [spacy](http://spacy.io)'s implementation of [sense2vec](https://github.com/explosion/sense2vec). It is based on the original sense2vec [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1511.06388). From the abstract:

> This paper presents a novel approach which addresses these concerns by modeling multiple embeddings for each word based on supervised disambiguation, which provides a fast and accurate way for a consuming NLP model to select a sense-disambiguated embedding. We demonstrate that these embeddings can disambiguate both contrastive senses such as nominal and verbal senses as well as nuanced senses such as sarcasm.

Answer (score 1):

On [this page](https://nlpprogress.com) you can find NLP STATE-OF-THE-ART publications and rank, particularly [word sense disambiguation - WSD SOTA](https://nlpprogress.com/english/word_sense_disambiguation.html). You might be interested on [supWSDemb](https://aclweb.org/anthology/D17-2018) and 
[UKB](https://aclweb.org/anthology/W18-2505) which are the supervised and unsupervised SOTA respectively at current time.